# Cannot take picture with Camera.takePicture

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm trying to make an activity which can take pictures, only problem is that the callback is never called. The preview does stop and the "Please wait" dialog appears, so everything is working fine till that part.

I'm testing on a Galaxy S3 i9300 with AOKP ROM installed.
Android version 4.3.1

PictureTaker.java

```
package ...;
import everything;

public class PictureTaker extends Activity  {
    private Preview mPreview;
    Camera mCamera;
    int numberOfCameras;
    int cameraCurrentlyLocked;

    public AlertDialog diag;
    protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    // The first rear facing camera
    int defaultCameraId;


    final Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d("Adnan", "onShutter");
        }
    };


    final Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        String picPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/billsterData/camTemp.jpg";

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            String TAG = "Adnan";
            diag.dismiss();

            Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to store picture...");
            final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 100;
            File pictureFile = new File(picPath);

            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    public void onExitPressed(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    public void takePic(View v) {
        Log.i("Adnan", "taking picture...");

        mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, mPicture);

        v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.popup));

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please wait");
        builder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progress_circular, null));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        diag = builder.create();
        diag.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.pic_taker_carry);

        // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
        // and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        RelativeLayout carry = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        mPreview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        carry.addView(mPreview,0);

        //setContentView(mPreview);

        // Find the total number of cameras available
        numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        // Find the ID of the default camera
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        this.mWakeLock.acquire();

        // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        cameraCurrentlyLocked = defaultCameraId;
        mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        this.mWakeLock.release();

        // Because the Camera object is a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mPreview.setCamera(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Preview.java

```
package ...;

import everything

public class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    public Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void switchCamera(Camera camera) {
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                        width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e ) {

        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        parameters.setJpegQuality(80);

        requestLayout();

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

}
```

Some related lines in logcat:

```
01-20 17:13:56.544   22594-5071/? E/exynos_param﹕ exynos_param_string_get: Unable to get data for key recording-hint
01-20 17:13:56.544   22594-5071/? E/exynos_param﹕ exynos_param_string_get: Unable to get data for key focus-areas
01-20 17:13:56.574   22594-5973/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_capture_thread: Starting thread
01-20 17:13:56.729  22594-22631/? E/exynos_camera﹕ Preview thread was already stopped!
01-20 17:13:56.739  22594-25719/? E/exynos_param﹕ exynos_param_data_set: Mismatching types for key horizontal-view-angle
01-20 17:13:56.744  22594-25719/? E/exynos_param﹕ exynos_param_string_get: Unable to get data for key recording-hint
01-20 17:13:56.744  22594-25719/? E/exynos_param﹕ exynos_param_string_get: Unable to get data for key focus-areas
01-20 17:13:56.744   22594-5974/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_preview_thread: Starting thread
01-20 17:13:58.709   22594-5975/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_picture_thread: Starting thread
01-20 17:13:58.804   22594-5973/? E/exynos_camera﹕ s5c73m3_interleaved_decode: Invalid jpeg start
01-20 17:13:58.804   22594-5973/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_capture: Unable to decode S5C73M3 interleaved
01-20 17:13:58.804   22594-5973/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_capture_thread: Unable to capture
01-20 17:14:15.479   22594-5974/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_preview_thread: Exiting thread
01-20 17:14:15.534   22594-5975/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_picture_thread: Exiting thread
01-20 17:14:15.534   22594-5973/? E/exynos_camera﹕ exynos_camera_capture_thread: Exiting thread
```

notice this one:

```
01-20 17:13:58.804   22594-5973/? E/exynos_camera﹕ s5c73m3_interleaved_decode: Invalid jpeg start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same problem on Galaxy S3 (I9300) with CyanogenMod 10.1 and above. Today I found the solution for this. I think it is a problem in the AOPK code.

You have to make sure that the aspect ratio of the previewsize and the picture sice is equal.

Try this code to get an picturesize without this problem:

```
private Camera.Size getBestPictureSize(List<Camera.Size> pictureSizes, int maxWidth, Size previewSize) {
    Comparator<Camera.Size> cmp = new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {
        public int compare(Camera.Size size_1, Camera.Size size_2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(size_1.width).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(size_2.width));
        }
    };
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetAspect = (double)previewSize.width / (double)previewSize.height;

    ArrayList<Camera.Size> matchedPictureSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>();


    for(Size pictureSize : pictureSizes) {
        double pictureAspect = (double)pictureSize.width / (double)pictureSize.height;

        if(pictureSize.width <= maxWidth && Math.abs(targetAspect - pictureAspect) < ASPECT_TOLERANCE) {
            matchedPictureSizes.add(pictureSize);
        }
    }

    Camera.Size bestPictureSize;
    if(!matchedPictureSizes.isEmpty()) {
        bestPictureSize = Collections.max(matchedPictureSizes, cmp);
    } else {
        bestPictureSize = Collections.max(pictureSizes, cmp);
    }

    return bestPictureSize;
}
```

I hope this code solve your problem.

Comment: I had the same issue in CM 10.2, so it may not be a bug, but the new standard. Once I set the preview to the correct aspect ratio, I was able to take pictures.